# how to display same size of images in boot strap carousel

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using the following code to display the images in Bootstrap carousel:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"> 
    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id($page->ID), 'child-page','', array('class' => "img-responsive img-shadow", 'alt' => get_the_title()))  ?>
    <?php echo $image; ?> 
</a>
```

I have added `add_image_size( 'child-page', 400, 200, true );` in functions.php but it is displaying the images of variable height.

How do I control size without having to optimize the images?

Answer (score 1):

i added the following css

```
.gallery-slider .thumbnail>img, .thumbnail a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: 170px !important;
}
```

to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Why not put in your `style.css`

```
.carousel-inner img{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution but its not working                                actually there is                                               .img-responsive, .thumbnail>img, .thumbnail a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
 height: auto; 
}problem is due to the height :auto;

Comment: So i used  following                                                  .gallery-slider .thumbnail>img, .thumbnail a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: 170px !important;
}               to overwrite height:auto                                  and now the problem has been solved

Comment: gud to know that ur problem is solved and sorry i was out for a long while :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can force your images to fit a specific width and height as proposed by @rockStar using CSS, however, that will result in ugly disproportionate images. There are plugins which allow you - *effortlessly* - to regenerate WordPress thumbnails in the dimensions you need them to be:

- [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)
- [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)

Cheers.